# Performing Fourier Analysis using Python for image reconstruction

Tags: python, image-processing, fft, analysis

I'm trying to perform a Fourier analysis on some shapes I produced using Python. I managed to obtain a 2D Fourier transform on the images as well as applying a Gaussian filter, however the inverse of the image with the Gaussian filter is being shifted and I don't know how to resolve it. I tried to take the real values only in the hopes that it would solve it but nothing changed. I'm demonstrating my code below, does someone have any ideas on what I could do?

```
#importing necessary libraries 
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter


#function to apply Gaussian filter to the Fourier transform
def apply_gaussian_filter(fourier_transform, sigma):
    return gaussian_filter(fourier_transform, sigma)

##code to produce an image of a box and perform Fourier analysis on it

#defining the size bounds of the box
w, h = 65, 65
box = [(50, 29), (w-50, h-30)]

#creating the image with a white background
im = Image.new("I", (w,h))
img = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

#producing the box shape
img.rectangle(box, fill = "white", outline = "white")

#convering image to numpy library
im_array = np.array(im)

#taking the 2D Fourier transform
fourier_box = np.fft.fft2(im_array)

#shifting the zero frequency component to the center
fourier_box_shifted = np.fft.fftshift(fourier_box)

#applying Gaussian filter to the Fourier transform of the box
sigma_box = 5
filtered_fourier_box = apply_gaussian_filter(np.abs(fourier_box_shifted), sigma_box)

##code to produce an image of a circle and perform Fourier analysis on it

#defining the size bounds of the shape
w_1, h_1 = 65, 65
circle = [(10, 10), (w_1-10, h_1-10)]

#creating the image with a white background
im_1 = Image.new("I", (w_1,h_1))
img_1 = ImageDraw.Draw(im_1)

#producing the circle shape
img_1.ellipse(circle, fill = "white", outline = "white")

#convering image to numpy library
im_1_array = np.array(im_1)

#taking the 2D Fourier transform
fourier_circle = np.fft.fft2(im_1_array)

#shifting the zero frequency component to the center
fourier_circle_shifted = np.fft.fftshift(fourier_circle)

#applying Gaussian filter to the Fourier transform of the circle
sigma_circle = 5
filtered_fourier_circle = apply_gaussian_filter(np.abs(fourier_circle_shifted), sigma_circle)

#applying inverse Fourier transform to the filtered Fourier data
inverse_filtered_box = np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(filtered_fourier_box)).real
inverse_filtered_circle = np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(filtered_fourier_circle)).real

#adjusting size of the graphs 
plt.figure(figsize=(13, 8))

#displaying the Fourier transform of the box 
plt.subplot(231)  
plt.imshow(np.log(np.abs(fourier_box_shifted) + 1))
plt.title('2D Fourier Transform Box')

#displaying the Fourier transform of the box with Gaussian filter
plt.subplot(232) 
plt.imshow(np.log(filtered_fourier_box + 1))
plt.title('Gaussian Filtered 2D Fourier Transform Box')

#displaying the inverse of the filtered Fourier box
plt.subplot(233)  
plt.imshow(np.abs(np.real(inverse_filtered_box)))
plt.title('Inverse Filtered Box')

#displaying the Fourier transform of the circle
plt.subplot(234)
plt.imshow(np.log(np.abs(fourier_circle_shifted) + 1))
plt.title('2D Fourier Transform Circle')

#displaying the Fourier transform of the circle with Gaussian filter
plt.subplot(235)
plt.imshow(np.log(filtered_fourier_circle + 1))
plt.title('Gaussian Filtered 2D Fourier Transform Circle')

#displaying the inverse of the filtered Fourier circle
plt.subplot(236)  
plt.imshow(np.abs(np.real(inverse_filtered_circle)))
plt.title('Inverse Filtered Circle')
```

[image]

The image I attached are the results I'm obtaining, the issue pertains to the inverse graphs.

Comment: You could apply "code" formatting via selecting the entire code in the [editor](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77994294/edit), and pressing the `{}` button above the editor box. It will add 4 spaces in front of every line, that's how code blocks are indicated in markdown.

Comment: Noted with thanks.

Comment: I suspect this is a sign convention thing in the transform. The natural FFT ends up with the Fourier transform DC component centred in the corner (0,0), but for display purposes it may be shifted to the middle of your viewscreen. It looks like the inverse expects to get its input in that form. If you do say "A" FFT and then immediately IFT does it end up shifted or not?  Also the Gaussian filter appears to be convolving the FFT in Fourier space rather than multiplying it which may not be what you wanted. Many real image Fourier transforms convert to complex conjugate symmetric form.

Answer (score 4):

After reading your code and trying to compare each step, I managed to identify a problem with your code: `apply_gaussian_filter(np.abs(fourier_circle_shifted), sigma_circle)`. Applying the gaussian on the absolute of `fourier_circle_shifted` will make you lose phase information, hence reconstruction would not work. Here are two functions that apply the Gaussian on the whole fft or on the absolute of it:

```
def filterAndReconstruct_Abs(im, sigma = 1):
    fftOfIm = np.fft.fft2(im) # fft2 on image
    fftOfIm_Shifted = np.fft.fftshift(fftOfIm) # shift
    fftOfIm_Filtered = gaussian_filter(np.abs(fftOfIm_Shifted), sigma) # gaussian on absolute!!
    imReconstructed = np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(fftOfIm_Filtered)).real # reconstruct
    return imReconstructed
def filterAndReconstruct_WithPhase(im, sigma = 1):
    fftOfIm = np.fft.fft2(im) # fft2 on image
    fftOfIm_Shifted = np.fft.fftshift(fftOfIm) # shift
    fftOfIm_Filtered = gaussian_filter(fftOfIm_Shifted, sigma) # gaussian on fft with phase!!
    imReconstructed = np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(fftOfIm_Filtered)).real # reconstruct
    return imReconstructed
```

And now let's give it an example of a rectangle:

```
im = np.zeros((1000, 1000)) # create empty array
im[200:800, 200:800] = 255 # draw a rectangle
sigma = 0.2 # define sigma
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols = 3, nrows = 1, sharex = True, sharey = True)
axs[0].imshow(im)
axs[1].imshow(filterAndReconstruct_Abs(im,sigma)+1, norm=LogNorm())
axs[2].imshow(filterAndReconstruct_WithPhase(im,sigma)+1, norm=LogNorm())
for ax in axs:
    ax.axis("off")
```

The results will be like this:

[image: Difference between the variations]

As you can see, the reconstruction with the FFT is the correct variation. Playing with your example, if you use `apply_gaussian_filter(fourier_circle_shifted, sigma_circle)` and a lower sigma,you will get some nice results as well.

Hope this helps you further, also the imports of my example:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
```